# Using Android Account Transfer API on Wear OS

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

Is it possible to use [Androids Account Transfer API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/account-transfer) with a usual Android phone as source and a Wear OS smart watch as receiver? According to the documentation the setup has to look like this:

- The source device must be running Android 4.0.1 (API level 14) or
  higher.
- The target device must be running Android 8.0 (API level 26)
  or higher.
- Both source and target devices must be running Google Play
  services version 11.2.0 or higher. You must build your APK using
  Google Play services SDK version 11.2.0 or higher.

I want to sync my phone's accounts to my smart watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to sync data from your Android phone to an android wear, I think [Google Fit API](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview) will do the job.

> Google Fit is an open ecosystem that allows developers to upload
>   fitness data to a central repository where users can access their data
>   from different devices and apps in one location:
>
> - Fitness apps can store data from any wearable or sensor.
> - Fitness apps can access data created by any app.
> - User's fitness data is persisted when they upgrade their fitness devices.

Also, it was mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/) that the least Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher is supported.

Comment: You are right! Although I was thinking about avoid sharing the data with Google and instead pushing it to my own server.